# SpEL conditional on bean id

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I have a Spring Bean file containing many `ThingConfigurationResource` beans. Depending on the System Property activeCfg (`-DactiveCfg=thing1`) I would like to set the `active` property value for each bean conditioned on if the bean id matches the System Property value.

I don't understand how to access the bean id inside the SpEL expression. This does not work `#this.id`

```
<bean class="ThingConfigurationResource" id="thing1">
  <property name="active" value="#{systemProperties.activeCfg == #this.id ? true : false}"/>
</bean>
```

I get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 41): Property or field 'id' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?
```

I don't have access to the program source code, thus I have to do this with SpEL.